# Know IP address of system which started EC2 instance

Tags: linux, unix, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am working with AWS, recently my account details (access key/secret key) has been compromised. They started 21 Ec2 instances. Is there a way to check that from which IP address AWS EC2 instance was started ?

Answer (score 2):

You can check this information if you have enabled [CloudTrail](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/). There should be "sourceIPAddress" for the event.

[EC2 Log Example](http://awsdocs.s3.amazonaws.com/awscloudtrail/latest/awscloudtrail-ug.pdf):

```
{
    "Records": [{
        "eventVersion": "1.0",
        "userIdentity": {
            "type": "IAMUser",
            "principalId": "EX_PRINCIPAL_ID",
            "arn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/Alice",
            "accessKeyId": "EXAMPLE_KEY_ID",
            "accountId": "123456789012",
            "userName": "Alice"
        },
        "eventTime": "2014-03-06T21:22:54Z",
        "eventSource": "ec2.amazonaws.com",
        "eventName": "StartInstances",
        "awsRegion": "us-west-2",
        "sourceIPAddress": "205.251.233.176",
        "userAgent": "ec2-api-tools 1.6.12.2",
```

Comment: you can also login to the aws management console, couldtrail, set filter name to the instance ID, then you can find out the source IP address.

Comment: As the cost were increasing ., we have terminated the instance, is there some other way through which we can find the IP address ?

Comment: this answer by Greg doesn't require the instance be running. Generally speaking, finding the culprit is the least of your problems- you are better off figuring out how you accidentally exposed your keys.

Comment: I fully agree, better focus how to secure your environment and ensure it will not happen again. You can not trust any credentials for your AWS account anymore... access keys/secret keys, ssh keys, users etc.